# Seeking quick-fix solution for geocoding

Tags: software-recommendations, geocoding

I am working on a prototype for a web-based trip planner and need to have a geocoding function (for the start and destination adresses), up and running the "easy" way.

My area that the prototype is covering is apprx.2*4 sqkm.

Which option is the fastest and easiest (to learn) as I have very limited time?

I have been looking into gisgraphy (downloading and geocoding in the database), nominatim/Mapquest etc. I prefer not be constrained to use a specific map provider, like Google or yahoo.

However, if necessary it is possible to change geocoder later on... for now I need the "quick fix"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geocoding is often a bit difficult to integrate, at least from my experience... it'd be nice if you could just plug it in and have it work right away (without having to consign oneself to an integrated map service, like Mapquest, etc).

I'm assuming your web app uses Javascript, and some server-side code of any platform.

I work at [SmartyStreets](https://smartystreets.com) where we perform address validation and geocoding. Our service, US Street Address API geocodes addresses, but because it's [CASS-Certified](https://smartystreets.com/articles/cass-processing) it also verifies that the addresses are correct and valid and will standardize them if they are not (something that Google/Mapquest do not do).

Since you'd rather not be constrained to a particular map provider, I'd suggest a service like the SmartyStreets [US Street Address API](https://smartystreets.com/products) which you can switch out anytime and remain totally transparent to your front-end. It's an [API](https://smartystreets.com/archive/api) you can hook into easily from any platform/language, and it integrates seamlessly with Javascript because the output is JSON.

If you care about speed and reliability, it's good to know that the US Street Address API is geo-distributed, with guaranteed uptime.

It's free to sign up and start using indefinitely, so if you need a quick-fix, that might do it for you.